# function &ID in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a Javascript function to change colors of a svg ellipse object with id="eye"

```
document.getElementById("eye").onmouseover = function() {
    changeColor()
};

function changeColor() {
    document.getElementById("eye").style.fill = "red";
}

document.getElementById("eye").onmouseout = function() {
    changeColor2()
};

function changeColor2() {
    document.getElementById("eye").style.fill = "green";
}
```

Now there are 2 more svg objects with id="nose" and id="mouth", how can I apply the same change color founction on these 2 objects? Yes I can repeat the founction 2 more times but there must be a better way to do it. Note The 3 objects shouldn't change color at the same time, which means there no need for loop.

Comment: id should be unique.

Comment: Do you see any 2 elements with same id here? :D

Answer (score 0):

you  mean like that? :

```
document.getElementById("eye").onmouseover = function() {
    changeColor("eye")
};
document.getElementById("nose").onmouseover = function() {
    changeColor("nose")
};
document.getElementById("mouth").onmouseover = function() {
    changeColor("mouth")
};

document.getElementById("eye").onmouseout = function() {
    changeColor2()
};
document.getElementById("nose").onmouseout = function() {
    changeColor2("nose")
};
document.getElementById("mouth").onmouseout = function() {
    changeColor2("mouth")
};

function changeColor(element) {
    document.getElementById(element).style.fill = "red";
}

function changeColor2(element) {
    document.getElementById(element).style.fill = "green";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a parameter to your functions:

```
function changeColor(element, color) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

document.getElementById("eye").onmouseover = function(){changeColor(this, "red")};
document.getElementById("eye").onmouseout = function(){changeColor(this, "green")};

document.getElementById("nose").onmouseover = function(){changeColor(this, "blue")};
document.getElementById("nose").onmouseout = function(){changeColor(this, "orange")};
```

**UPDATED**

Syntax for background colour fixed(instead of `.style.fill` it is `.style.backgroundColor`)

**[See Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewewwa19/)**

**[Reducing element look-ups](http://jsfiddle.net/ewewwa19/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a closure like this:

```
// Caching elements and closures
var eye = document.getElementById("eye"),
    nose = document.getElementById("nose"),
    mouth = document.getElementById("mouth"),
    change_to_green = change_group_color("green"),
    change_to_red = change_group_color("red");


eye.onmouseover = change_to_green;
eye.onmouseout = change_to_red;

nose.onmouseover = change_to_green;
eye.onmouseout = change_to_red;

mouth.onmouseover = change_to_green;
mouth.onmouseout = change_to_red;


function change_group_color(color){
    var elem_group = [eye, nose, mouth];

    return function(){
        var i,l;
        for(i=0, l=elem_group.length ; i<l ; i++){
            elem_group[i].style.fill = color;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the handler will point to the element that you registered the event with

```
function onMouseOver() {
     this.style.fill = "red";
}

function onMouseOut {
     this.style.fill = "green";
}

var eye = document.getElementById("eye");
var nose = document.getElementById("nose");
eye.onmouseover = nose.onmouseover = onMouseOver;
eye.onmouseout = nose.onmouseout = onMouseOout;
```